# Custom field normalization

Tags: salesforce, textarea, normalization, apex-code

I have created a custom field of type Text Area in my Sandbox environment and would like to know how to normalize the text typed into this custom field.

In order to make a normalization I've implememted the following method:

```
public String domainNormalization(Account accountObj) {
    String domain = accountObj.Domain__c;
    if (domain != null) {
        domain = domain.replaceAll('[ ]+', '');
        domain = domain.replaceAll('[,;:*]+', ' ');
        domain = domain.replaceAll('(https?://www.|https?|www.)', ' ');
        domain = domain.replaceAll('(A-Za-z\\d._~:/?#\\[\\]@!$&\'()*+,;=-)', ' ');
        accountObj.Domain__c = domain;
        return domain;
    }
    return '';
}
```

But when I am able to add in the domain field: 
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laKcr.png)

The code in the normalization method does not work because I get the following:
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67cwJ.png)

It should always look for string(domainname) + dot "." + the extension of the domain(com, eu, bg and etc). Where the separator between these must be a single space for example: domain.com secondomain.com thirddomain.com

Coud you please advise how to normalize the text typed in the domain field in order to achive the same result in the given example?

I also would like to know is there a way to get all possible domain extensions(com, eu, bg and etc)? Do I need special consideration about domains such as for instance (co.uk)?

Regards,

Dilyan